# git config diff.name-only?

Tags: git, git-diff, git-config

Is it possible to make `git diff` show `--name-only` output by default (i.e. without having to explicitly type `--name-only`)?

I know you can set defaults on some git options with `git config`, but I can't figure out how to map between the command line options and the config options. I rely on Googling to see others who've already done it, but I don't see anyone who's wanted this particular default setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [GitConfig](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) there is no such option among configuration variables, so you can only achieve this using [Git Aliases](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases)

```
git config --global alias.diffn 'diff --name-only'
```

Or setting it manually in `.gitconfig` under `[alias]` section:

```
diffn = diff --name-only
```

I would also recommend looking at [dotfiles](https://dotfiles.github.io/) repos for more inspiration on aliases and `.gitconfig`

Comment: I just tried this. For some reason it doesn't work, I still get the file content diff. But I'm going to mark this as the right answer soon anyway. I checked my `.gitconfig` to verify that the line got added, and in the right place.

Comment: Actually it seems even another alias `log = log --format=oneline` isn't working. My `.gitconfig` file is a symlink, and other config works. Something strange is happening to the `[alias]` section.

Comment: I read more and seems that alias can't replace the name of default tool (apparently there is a calling precedence). And since there is not default options seems like only way is to create similar alias. I updated the answer

Comment: That's unfortunate. Thanks for researching that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **bash alias**

```
echo "alias gitdiffname='git diff --name-only'">>~/.profile

source ~/.profile

gitdiffname
```

Comment: I should have said in my original post, I know I can use aliases but I'd like to avoid remembering more commands. (I use key bindings more than aliases for that reason, but I run out of keystrokes).